# How to create 2 lists from one list based on predicate using stram().reduce()

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce, predicate

I need to create 2 lists based on a predicate by using stream().reduce(). I got a similar code but it's not working.

```
localRequestDTOList.stream().reduce((res, item) ->{
       res[predicate(item) ? 'a' : 'b'].push(item);
       return res;
}, { a: [], b: [] });
```

The predicate is shown below.

```
public static Predicate<LocalRequestDTO> payToVendor() {
    return request -> (request.getSuffix().equals("00"));
}
```

What I want is from localRequestDTOList create two lists with the condition that their `request.getsuffix().equals("00")` or not. I simply put the two lists as `a` and `b`.

Comment: could you post complete compilable code please?

Comment: Your first code snippet is not valid Java syntax, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about how to partition a list by using `reduce`. That's like asking how to hammer a nail using a screwdriver. It would be better to use the correct method for the purpose.

If you can use `collect()` then you could make use of `Collectors.partitioningBy()`:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<LocalRequestDTO>> partition = localRequestDTOList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(payToVendor()));
List<LocalRequestDTO> a = partition.get(true);
List<LocalRequestDTO> b = partition.get(false);
```

Comment: If you need to split to more than 2 lists, use `groupingBy(...)` instead.